# Run Ubuntu as administrator

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, administrator, root

When I start my session in Ubuntu there is a message that tells me I have no administrator access:

[image]

But when I write this command nothing happens.

How to fix this to get access to all folders in the PC?

Comment: What command did you use? “sudo root” would switch you to root which is what the message is indicating

Comment: What exactly do you need to access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need administrative privileges for a command, you can use `sudo [command]` to run the command as an administrator. It'll ask you to enter your password. Enter it and the command should run. If you want to just be the admin without typing `sudo [command]` every time, you can type `su` and it will ask for your password. Once you do that, you will become root (another term for administrator). It is not recommended to become root, as you could mess up your system if you end up doing the wrong things. It is best to just do `sudo [command]` to give root privileges to commands that need it. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo *command*
```

or

```
sudo su
```

The first command will give administrative powers for that command. The shell will remember that you have those powers for the commands in the next few minutes and will not ask password when you use it (on Ubuntu).

The second will make give you admin powers for the rest of the duration of the shell.

By default, Ubuntu does not create a root account with password. During the installation process, Ubuntu asks you to create a password for a common user.
So, using only "su" will prompt for a password that do not exist and will return a authentication failure (that is what happens on my Pop!OS).